# How to Set Specific Site Collection as SharePoint Search Scope using C#?

Tags: development

I have two site collections as Portal1 and Portal2. In Portal2, I have enterprise search centre and will add custom Search scope for Portal1 site collection using C#. I deployed project in Portal2 and activated feature. With properties.Feature.parent as SPSite, I got Site of Portal2. How can I get Portal1 (SpSite site)?

scope.Rules.CreateUrlRule(ScopeRuleFilterBehavior.Include, UrlScopeRuleType.HostName, **site.RootWeb.Url**);

Site.RootWeb.Url should get URL of Portal1.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the url of Portal1, you can directly use it instead of `site.RootWeb.Url`. If you need *SPSite* object of Portal1 you can use :

```
using (SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite([Portal1Url]))
{
...
}
```

If you dont know the url of Portal1,You should know have at least one property to find the site collection in the web application.Below is the example if you know *Title* of rootweb:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
if (site != null)
{
SPWebApplication webApp = site.WebApplication;
string targetUrl = string.Empty;
foreach (SPSite siteToSearch in webApp.Sites.Where
(siteToSearch => siteToSearch.RootWeb.Title == "Portal1 Title"))
{
   targetUrl = siteToSearch.Url;
}

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, your example works fine for my solution. But I decided to solve my issue with property bag. I set the property with powershell. Then, I get the site from SPFarm.Local.Properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the URL for Portal1 from a feature activated in Portal2 you will need to either get it from the SPWebApplication and use logic to determine which SPSite object to use, use a hard-coded URL to create a Portal1 SPSite object, or use a feature property to define the URL to use to create a Portal1 SPSite object.

Somewhere along the line you will have to define a hard-coded or property-based value that will enable you to create an SPSite object, unless you know a way to achieve the same using logic.

Hope this helps.